# Merging multiple meshes with transformation matrix into a single mesh in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl, matrix-multiplication

I try to merge multiple meshes with a transformation matrix into a single mesh.
Each mesh has 4 data sets.

1. Vertices
2. Indices
3. Texture Coordinates
4. Normals

The way I'm trying to do it is supposed to be lazy and not cost that much CPU.
It is a 3 step process.

1. Multiply each vertex and normal with the transformation matrix.
2. Merge the Vertices, Texture Coordinates and Normals of each mesh into 3 big arrays.
3. Merge the Indices of each mesh into a single array but use the sum of the previous meshes as an offset. For example: If mesh 1 has 800 indices then 800 has to be added to all of the indices from mesh 2.

This method has two big problems.

1. Duplicate vertices are not shared
2. Parts that are invisible due to clipping are not removed

But that is OK as this is supposed to be a lazy method with not much CPU usage. It is already optimal for creating meshes for grass and bushes.

I have attempted an implementation of this method which looks like this:

```
public static final MeshData mergeLazy(List<MeshData> meshes, List<Matrix4f> transformations) {

    int lengthVertices = 0;
    int lengthNormals = 0;
    int lengthTexCoords = 0;
    int lengthIndices = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> indexLengths = new ArrayList<>();

    for(MeshData mesh : meshes) {

        lengthVertices += mesh.getVertices().length;
        lengthNormals += mesh.getNormals().length;
        lengthTexCoords += mesh.getTextureCoordinates().length;
        int length = mesh.getIndices().length;
        lengthIndices += length;
        indexLengths.add(length);
    }

    float[] vertices = new float[lengthVertices];
    float[] texCoords = new float[lengthTexCoords];
    float[] normals = new float[lengthNormals];
    int[] indices = new int[lengthIndices];

    int iv = 0;
    int ivt = 0;
    int ivn = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int indexLength = 0;

    for(int im = 0; im < meshes.size(); im++) {

        MeshData mesh = meshes.get(im);
        float[] mVertices = mesh.getVertices();
        float[] mTexCoords = mesh.getTextureCoordinates();
        float[] mNormals = mesh.getNormals();
        int[] mIndices = mesh.getIndices();
        Matrix4f transformation = transformations.get(im);

        for(int index = 0; index < mVertices.length; index += 3) {

            Vector3f vertex = MatrixUtil.multiply(transformation, mVertices[index], mVertices[index + 1], mVertices[index + 2]);
            vertices[iv++] = vertex.x;
            vertices[iv++] = vertex.y;
            vertices[iv++] = vertex.z;

            Vector3f normal = MatrixUtil.multiply(transformation, mNormals[index], mNormals[index + 1], mNormals[index + 2]);
            normals[ivn++] = normal.x;
            normals[ivn++] = normal.y;
            normals[ivn++] = normal.z;
        }

        for(int index = 0; index < mTexCoords.length; index++) {

            texCoords[ivt++] = mTexCoords[index];
        }

        for(int index = 0; index < mIndices.length; index++) {

            indices[i++] = indexLength + mIndices[index];
        }

        indexLength += indexLengths.get(im);
    }

    MeshData data = new MeshData();
    data.setIndices(indices);
    data.setNormals(normals);
    data.setTextureCoordinates(texCoords);
    data.setVertices(vertices);

    return data;
}
```

In the end I actually have a single mesh and the multiplying of the transformation also works.... for rotation and scaling, but here come the problems.

The multiplying with the transformation does NOT work for the translation.
My method for multiplying a matrix with a vector looks like this:

```
public static final Vector3f multiply(Matrix4f matrix, float x, float y, float z) {

    Vector3f result = new Vector3f();
    result.x = x * matrix.m00 + y * matrix.m01 + z * matrix.m02;
    result.y = x * matrix.m10 + y * matrix.m11 + z * matrix.m12;
    result.z = x * matrix.m20 + y * matrix.m21 + z * matrix.m22;
    return result;
}
```

And the second problem is that the textures of the second mesh are somewaht off.

Here is a picture:
[image: Error]

As you can see the second mesh only has about 1/4 of the actual texture.

The code I used to generate this mesh looks like this:

```
    Material grassMaterial = new Material();
    grassMaterial.setMinBrightness(0.1F);
    grassMaterial.setColorMap(new Texture(new XImgTextureReader().read(new FileInputStream("res/textures/grass2.ximg"))));
    grassMaterial.setAffectedByLight(true);
    grassMaterial.setTransparent(true);
    grassMaterial.setUpwardsNormals(true);
    grassMaterial.setFog(fog);

    MeshData quad = Quad.generateMeshData(
        new Vector3f(0.0F, 1F, 0.0F),
        new Vector3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F),
        new Vector3f(1F, 0.0F, 0.0F),
        new Vector3f(1F, 1F, 0.0F)
    );

    StaticMesh grassMesh = new StaticMesh(MeshUtil.mergeLazy(Arrays.asList(quad, quad), Arrays.asList(
        MatrixUtil.createTransformationMatrx(
            new Vector3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F),
            new Vector3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F),
            new Vector3f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F)
        ),
        MatrixUtil.createTransformationMatrx(
            new Vector3f(0F, 0.0F, -0F),
            new Vector3f(0.0F, 90.0F, 0.0F),
            new Vector3f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F)
        )
    )));
    grassMesh.setCullMode(StaticMesh.CULLING_DISABLED);

    Entity grass = new Entity();
    grass.setShaderPipeline(shaderPipeline);
    grass.setMaterial(grassMaterial);
    grass.setMesh(grassMesh);
    grass.setTranslation(0, 0, 1);
```

My question now is: What did I do wrong? Why is the texture so weird and why does the multiplication with the transformation not work for the translation?

If you need more of the code, I have a GitHub Repo with the Eclipse Project here: https://github.com/RalleYTN/Heroica-Fabulis

Comment: It has to be `result.x = x*matrix.m00 + y*matrix.m01 + z*matrix.m02 + 1.0*matrix.m03;` ...

Comment: Wouldn't the whole approach only work when the meshes are using the same texture?

Comment: @BDL yes. It is a lazy method to create alot of different grass and bush meshes which use the same texture from each side.

Comment: @Rabbid76 the result is still the same but yes you are correct it should be like that.

Comment: Oh, probably it has to be `result.x = x*matrix.m00 + y * matrix.m10 + z*matrix.m20 + matrix.m30;`. In common the translation is (m30, m31, m32). Note there is a difference between a mathematical matrix and the memory image of an OpenGL matrix.

Comment: @Rabbid76 now it moves but not as it should. if I only set the X coordinate to 0.5F the quad is diagonal. but not fully diagonal maybe 30°.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rabbid76 I came closer to my answer and now I have finally found the problem.
The first problem with the translation not working was fixed by multiplying the transformation vertically instead of horizontally. Thanks again @Rabidd76 .

And the reason why the textures where so weird is because I merged the indices incorrectly. I should not have taken the sum of all indices in the meshes before as offset but the sum of the vertices.

Here is now the working method:

```
public static final MeshData mergeLazy(List<MeshData> meshes, List<Matrix4f> transformations) {

    ArrayList<Float> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    int offset = 0;
    int m = 0;

    for(MeshData mesh : meshes) {

        Matrix4f transformation = transformations.get(m);
        float[] mVertices = mesh.getVertices();
        float[] mNormals = mesh.getNormals();

        for(int index = 0; index < mesh.getVertices().length; index += 3) {

            Vector3f vertex = MatrixUtil.multiply(transformation, mVertices[index], mVertices[index + 1], mVertices[index + 2]);
            vertices.add(vertex.x);
            vertices.add(vertex.y);
            vertices.add(vertex.z);

            Vector3f normal = MatrixUtil.multiply(transformation, mNormals[index], mNormals[index + 1], mNormals[index + 2]);
            normals.add(normal.x);
            normals.add(normal.y);
            normals.add(normal.z);
        }

        ListUtil.addFloatArray(texCoords, mesh.getTextureCoordinates());
        int[] mIndices = mesh.getIndices();

        for(int index : mIndices) {

            indices.add(index + offset);
        }

        offset += mVertices.length / 3;
        m++;
    }

    MeshData mesh = new MeshData();
    mesh.setIndices(ListUtil.toPrimitiveIntArray(indices));
    mesh.setNormals(ListUtil.toPrimitiveFloatArray(normals));
    mesh.setTextureCoordinates(ListUtil.toPrimitiveFloatArray(texCoords));
    mesh.setVertices(ListUtil.toPrimitiveFloatArray(vertices));

    return mesh;
}
```

Comment: i'm facing a similar problem and your approach helped me, but how did you calculate the transformation matrix of the second mesh? In order to use the same mesh in a new node, I would need a transformation matrix right? Can you help with this?